# Where can I learn using absolute value function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I'm in High School and my textbooks have like skipped a lesson of modulus,i.e. $|x|$ in previous classes. 
I know that $$|-4|=4 $$
but how does

$$|x|=\begin{cases} x &\text{ if } x\geq0\\-x&\text{ if } x<0\end{cases}$$

This negative value of $x$ is what I don't get. If modulus gives positive values, how can $f(x)$ give a negative value?

Ps: I have found these problems while learning sets.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) is a starting point. It has a nice explanation.

Comment: I went there. I got it too. Its the -x in f(x) that i dont understand

Comment: Look at the picture on the right there, with $-3$ in $f(3)$. So $|-3|=3$.

Comment: I get the |-3|=3(Sorry to sound dumb:)) Its the f(x)= |x| i dont get that says f(x) is negative when x is negative where f(x) should be just x

Comment: here is something for you https://sydney.edu.au/stuserv/documents/maths_learning_centre/absolutevalues.pdf

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369950/my-teacher-describes-absolute-value-confusingly-x-pm-x-quad-textif-ensp/2369953#comment4883915_2369950) and in particular the specific comment that the link leads to.

Comment: Thank You everyone for the help

Answer (score 6):

> (this negative value of x is what i dont get. If modulus gives positive values,how can f(x) give a negative value)

The definition might seem confusing at first, but it is in fact very logical:
$$|x| = \begin{cases} x & x \ge 0 \\ -x & x< 0\end{cases}$$
You should read this as follows:

> The **absolute value** of $x$, written as $|x|$, is equal to:
>
> - $x$ itself if $x$ is positive;
> - $-x$ if $x$ is negative.

Indeed: when $x$ is negative, $-x$ is positive!

Take an example, for $x = -3$ you would get:
$$|\color{red}{-3}| = -(\color{red}{-3}) = 3$$

---

Or put differently: we probably think of $|-3|=3$ as *"dropping the minus sign"*, but that's hard to put into symbols if we want to write down a symbolical definition. We can however easily *add an extra minus* and of course this achieves the exact same thing since $-(-x) = x$.

Comment: Thank You very much......Its so clear now and you have explained it like the best way possible

Comment: @AshishShukla You're welcome and thanks; I just added a bit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $-x$ doesn't mean that the number is negative (even though there's a negative sign!)  When $x$ is *already* negative, $-x$ is positive.